# Swift Command Line Tool utilizing Process() and multithreading crashes after a certain number of execution rounds (~3148)

Tags: swift, multithreading, thread-safety, bcrypt, command-line-tool

I implemented a password generator script in Swift which utilizes `Process()` to execute Mac OS X command line tasks. The passwords themselves are just random Strings which then are encrypted (bcrypt) by the command line task as follows:

```sh
/usr/sbin/htpasswd -bnBC 10 '' this_is_the_password | /usr/bin/tr -d ':\n'
```

Also multiple threads are used to generate passwords with their hashes in parallel.

**Note:** Both the **multithreading** and the **command line task** (compared to serveral other native Swift libraries I tried) improved performance in terms of execution time drastically.

### The Problem

The Programm runs fine for the first *~3148* rounds and **always** crashes around this number (problably correlated to the number of threads running).
For example, if I configure *2000* passwords the code executes as expected terminates without any errors.

### Common Error Messages

Setting a breakpoint in `Process+Pipe.swift` in the `catch` block of the `execute(...)` function at `BREAKPOINT_1` results in:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGCHLD
```

```
po error.localizedDescription
"The operation couldn\\U2019t be completed. (NSPOSIXErrorDomain error 9 - Bad file descriptor)"
```

When uncommenting the four `//return self.hash(string, cost: cost)` code snippets to ignore the error the following errors finally crash the execution (again in `execute(...)`, but not necessarily in the `catch` block):

```
Program stops ...
Thread 32: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x700003e6bfd4)
... on manual continue ...
Thread 2: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x700007e85fd4)
```

```
po process
error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0x700003e6bf40.
```

### Code

The relevant code componets are the `Main.swift` which initialized and starts (and later stops) the `PasswordGenerator` and then loops *n* times to get passwords via `nextPassword()` from the `PasswordGenerator`. The `PasswordGenerator` itself utilized `execute(...)` from the `Process` extension to run commandline tasks which generate the hash.

#### Main.swift

```
class Main {
  private static func generate(...) {
    ...
    PasswordGenerator.start()
    for _ in 0..<n {
      let nextPassword = PasswordGenerator.nextPassword()
      let readablePassword = nextPassword.readable
      let password = nextPassword.hash
      ...
    }
    PasswordGenerator.stop()
    ...
  }
}
```

#### PasswordGenerator.swift

The `PasswordGenerator` runs multiple Threads in parallel.
`nextPassword()` tries to get a password (if there is one in the `passwords` Array) or else waits for *100* seconds.

```
struct PasswordGenerator {
  typealias Password = (readable: String, hash: String)
  
  private static let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
  private static var active = false
  private static var passwords: [Password] = []
  
  static func nextPassword() -> Password {
    self.semaphore.wait()
    if let password = self.passwords.popLast() {
      self.semaphore.signal()
      return password
    } else {
      self.semaphore.signal()
      sleep(100)
      return self.nextPassword()
    }
  }
  
  static func start(
      numberOfWorkers: UInt = 32,
      passwordLength: UInt = 10,
      cost: UInt = 10
  ) {
      self.active = true
      
      for id in 0..<numberOfWorkers {
          self.runWorker(id: id, passwordLength: passwordLength, cost: cost)
      }
  }
  
  static func stop() {
    self.semaphore.wait()
    self.active = false
    self.semaphore.signal()
  }
  
  private static func runWorker(
    id: UInt,
    passwordLength: UInt = 10,
    cost: UInt = 10
  ) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
      var active = true
      repeat {
        // Update active.
        self.semaphore.wait()
        active = self.active
        print("numberOfPasswords: \(self.passwords.count)")
        self.semaphore.signal()
        
        // Generate Password.
        // Important: The bycrypt(cost: ...) step must be done outside the Semaphore!
        let readable = String.random(length: Int(passwordLength))
        let password = Password(readable: readable, hash: Encryption.hash(readable, cost: cost))
        
        // Add Password.
        self.semaphore.wait()
        self.passwords.append(password)
        self.semaphore.signal()
      } while active
    }
  }
}
```

#### Encryption.swift

```
struct Encryption {
  static func hash(_ string: String, cost: UInt = 10) -> String {
    // /usr/sbin/htpasswd -bnBC 10 '' this_is_the_password | /usr/bin/tr -d ':\n'
    
    let command = "/usr/sbin/htpasswd"
    let arguments: [String] = "-bnBC \(cost) '' \(string)".split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
    
    let result1 = Process.execute(
      command: command,//"/usr/sbin/htpasswd",
      arguments: arguments//["-bnBC", "\(cost)", "''", string]
    )
    
    let errorString1 = String(
      data: result1?.error?.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile() ?? Data(),
      encoding: String.Encoding.utf8
    ) ?? ""
    guard errorString1.isEmpty else {
//      return self.hash(string, cost: cost)
      fatalError("Error: Command \(command) \(arguments.joined(separator: " ")) failed with error: \(errorString1)")
    }
    
    guard let output1 = result1?.output else {
//    return self.hash(string, cost: cost)
      fatalError("Error: Command \(command) \(arguments.joined(separator: " ")) failed! No output.")
    }
      
    let command2 = "/usr/bin/tr"
    let arguments2: [String] = "-d ':\n'".split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
    
    let result2 = Process.execute(
      command: command2,
      arguments: arguments2,
      standardInput: output1
    )
    
    let errorString2 = String(
      data: result2?.error?.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile() ?? Data(),
      encoding: String.Encoding.utf8
    ) ?? ""
    guard errorString2.isEmpty else {
//      return self.hash(string, cost: cost)
      fatalError("Error: Command \(command) \(arguments.joined(separator: " ")) failed with error: \(errorString2)")
    }
    
    guard let output2 = result2?.output else {
//      return self.hash(string, cost: cost)
      fatalError("Error: Command \(command) \(arguments.joined(separator: " ")) failed! No output.")
    }
    
    guard
      let hash = String(
        data: output2.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile(),
        encoding: String.Encoding.utf8
      )?.replacingOccurrences(of: "$2y$", with: "$2a$")
    else {
      fatalError("Hash: String replacement failed!")
    }
    
    return hash
  }
}
```

#### Process+Pipe.swift

```
extension Process {
  static func execute(
    command: String,
    arguments: [String] = [],
    standardInput: Any? = nil
  ) -> (output: Pipe?, error: Pipe?)? {
    let process = Process()
    process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: command)
    process.arguments = arguments
    
    let outputPipe = Pipe()
    let errorPipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = outputPipe
    process.standardError = errorPipe
    
    if let standardInput = standardInput {
      process.standardInput = standardInput
    }
    
    do {
      try process.run()
    } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      // BREAKPOINT_1
      return nil
    }
    
    process.waitUntilExit()
    
    return (output: outputPipe, error: errorPipe)
  }
}
```

### Question(s)

1. **Why does the program crash?**
2. Why does it not crash for also huge numbers like *2000* passwords?
3. Is the multithreading implemented correct?
4. Is there a problem in the `execute(...)` code?

Comment: I seem to be hitting this same issue. Did you ever find a solution or explanation?

Comment: Until now I had no real solution for this issue.
The workaround was to save every 2000 iterations to the disc and start the program over, using the written data and continuing at the next iteration.
In the given context, this was an acceptable workaround, but it was certainly not ideal. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a fix while researching this bug. It seems that, despite what the documentation claims, `Pipe` will not automatically close its reading filehandle.

So if you add a `try outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.close()` after reading from it, that will fix the issue.

Comment: It seems that this basically did the trick! At first it did not work, but then I remembered to close `result1?.error` and `result2?.error` as well in addition to `output1` and `output2`.
The program then ran seamlessly for over +16000 rounds.
Thank you! Also I hope this helps other people too. ;)

Comment: Excellent! As I posted in the bug link below, this does seem to be a Swift bug, according to the documentation you should not need to close the file handles, but it seems you do have to. Let's see if it gets fixed.

Comment: I am curious, too. :)
p.s. the link in your bug report includes the closing bracket ")" of that line and therefore leads to the "not found" page of the apple documentation.

Comment: I had the same issue like 6 months ago (for a password related problem too btw), and indeed, closing the pipes was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is a Swift bug. I did some testing and could reproduce it by just running a lot of `Process.run()`. Filed an issue against Swift:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-15522